# ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8): Ruby 1.9.3 render view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

I have a problem when try to build one dropdown in view with rails

```
<div class='dropdown_menu'>
  <select id="venue_id" class="droppy" name="venue_id" onchange="submit();">
    <% @venues.each do |venue| %>
    <option value="<%= venue.id %>"<% if session[:venue] == venue.id %> selected<% end %>><%= venue.title %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
</div>
```

when build the option <%= venue.title %> I got a error

ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):

I tried some solutions but do not work

Comment: I'm curious, what is the value of `venue.title`? I presume you've read about a `# coding: utf-8` comment somewhere? (don't know how it's done in ERB though)

Comment: I need to configure the project to ignore all characters that can not be converted to UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Fixed this, only used gem 'mysql2' and change adapter in my database.yml, and change the encoding

staging:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: data_basename
    username: root
    encoding: utf8